# how to add properties to objects dynamically in c#

Tags: .net-3.5, properties

I want to add the properties to the class / object dynamically in c# in VS 3.5. how can i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/c-dynamic-properties

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an object that supports *run-time* addition of properties, and you can use C# 4.0, you can use [System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
myObject.AnswerToUltimateQuestionOfTheUniverse = 42;
```

EDIT: I see that you have now explictly mentioned C# 3.0. This is no longer applicable.

Comment: still, in the future this will be relevant. +1 :)

Comment: please see again , I have mentioned 3.5 not 3.0. I think we can do this by Dictionary or Hash table but how to achieve exact?

Answer (score 0):

Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically with the Decorator Pattern:
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx