# How to create property at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to create property in a class via code at runtime (Like ViewBag of MVC3) in C#?

I want to create property of custom type in a class as we create property in ViewBag of MVC3.

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797778/creating-a-class-like-asp-net-mvc-3-viewbag

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) - this will allow you to add as many "properties" as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic type in .NET 4 will allow you to create properties at runtime; I think ViewBag is actually an instance of the dynamic type.

By the way, I think what you're looking for is creating properties at *runtime* - creating properties at compile time would mean adding a getter and a setter to your code as you would normally do!