# C# How add runtime property in Class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have class like,

```
public class GraphDataTable
    {
        string customer;

        public string Customer
        {
            get { return customer; }
            set { customer = value; }
        }
        string target;

        public string Target
        {
            get { return target; }
            set { target = value; }
        }

    }
```

and I have another class where I am creating object of GraphDataTable, and list which List which contains {FORECASTED, QUALIFIED, QUOTED, WON, LOST}

Now, I want to create new properties which are added in GraphDataTable class from list.

How I can achieve this?

So new result which I require is GraphDataTable contains properties Customer, Target, FORECASTED, QUALIFIED, QUOTED, WON, LOST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the list of attributes in your objects `{FORECASTED, QUALIFIED, QUOTED, WON, LOST}` is your `Target` ?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime

Comment: 'Target' is another property, and I want to add {FORECASTED, QUALIFIED, QUOTED, WON, LOST} these as properties.

Comment: This can be achieved using reflection

Comment: It is not possible with normal object. You will have to use dynamic expando object..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add properties to a existing object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329489/dynamically-add-properties-to-a-existing-object)