# Add dynamically properties into a class without recompiling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to know if is it possible to dynamically add properties into a class without recompiling AND keep have the possibility to use IntelliSense on it ?

The only way I found is to use `dynamic` classes but IntelliSense doesn't work on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329489/dynamically-add-properties-to-a-existing-object

Comment: Nope, not if you want IntelliSense

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic` is the only way to add properties to objects dynamically.

Properties of dynamic objects are created at runtime and cannot be resolved before compilation.