# Dynamic Auto updating (to UI, Grid) binding list in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, data-binding, idynamicobject

I'm not even sure if I'm doing this correctly. But basically I have a list of objects that are built out of a class/interface. From there, I am binding the list to a `DataGridView` that is on a Windows Form (C#)

Here the list is a Sync list which will auto update the UI, in this case `DataGridView`.

Every thing works fine now, but now i would like to have the List should have an dynamic object, that is the object will have by default two static property (ID, Name), and at run time user will select remaining properties. These should be bind to the data grid. Any update on the list should be auto reflected in the grid.

I am aware that, we can use dynamic objects, but i would like to know , how to approach for solution,

```
datagridview.DataSource = myData;  // myData is AutoUpdateList<IPersonInfo>
```

Now `IPersonInfo` is the type of object, need to add dynamic properties for this type at runtime.

```
public class AutoUpdateList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private ISynchronizeInvoke _SyncObject;
    private Action<ListChangedEventArgs> _FireEventAction;

    public AutoUpdateList()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public AutoUpdateList(ISynchronizeInvoke syncObject)
    {
        _SyncObject = syncObject;
        _FireEventAction = FireEvent;
    }

    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_SyncObject == null)
            {
                FireEvent(args);
            }
            else
            {
                _SyncObject.Invoke(_FireEventAction, new object[] { args });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: Log Here
        }
    }

    private void FireEvent(ListChangedEventArgs args)
    { 
        base.OnListChanged(args);             
    }
}
```

Could you help out on this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way for you is 'to simulate' the properties. I guess the best way would be the [ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) implementing, the great example is [here](http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/02/04/simulating-fields).

Once I faced similar issue. For my case I've taken [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c) approach. This just might be helpful for you.

Also, there is a way (it's not about anything 'dynamic') to have a base class with fulls set of properties you gonna use. But it won't work if you don't have all properties before the runtime.

Comment: I could add/remove properties by dynamic properties. Only concerns is these should be auto updated in status grid.

Comment: And you have the ITypedList way. All you need after the implementation is to pass the new property name when you're adding new element to collection. By collection I mean the MasterRecordCollection instanse as in example in [this](http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/02/04/simulating-fields) article. I did check yesterday. All you need is to update DataSource of your DataGridView every time when new property is created.

Comment: I mean new column will be automatically added after you update the DataSource