# Linq to Compare 2 Objects

Tags: c#

I have two objects.

```
public class GlobalSettings
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

I need to compare these two objects. Depend on the property values of `GlobalSettings` i need to remove the property from `UserSettings`.

For eg.

From `GlobalSettings` property `A` value is `false` means i want to remove that property from `UserSettings`. Then i need to remove propery `A` from `UserSettings` like below.

```
public class UserSettings
{
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do this `linq`?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the property"?

Comment: Why you dont' define `UserSettings` as `Dictionary`?

Comment: LINQ has no relation to this code.

Comment: @ColmPrunty, hi, can u pls see my updates in questions?

Comment: Following post might be helpful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c

Comment: You can't delete code by using that same code, it doesn't make any sense. Do you want to do something like, relate the two, and use global settings' property if it is set, and user settings if it isn't?

Comment: @ColmPrunty, yes exactly i need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to automate this you could using Linq and reflection - e.g.

```
  var query = from aProp in a.GetType().GetProperties()
              let aValue = aProp.GetValue(a)
              let bProp = b.GetType().GetProperty(aProp.Name)
              let bValue = bProp.GetValue(b)
              where !aValue.Equals(bValue)
              select new { aProp.Name, aValue, bValue };

  var allTheSame = !query.Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the 'Remove' part of your question, I think you will be much better off using a `Dictionary` rather than a `Type` for your settings.

You can't remove properties from normal static C# Types, but you can easily remove entries from Dictionaries using the `Remove(key)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `UserSettings` inherits from `GlobalSettings` and in this example, if you use UserSettings.A, if will check if that is false in its parent class, and use UserSettings.A if it is false, and GlobalSettings.A if it's true.

```
public class GlobalSettings
{
    public virtual bool A { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings : GlobalSettings
{
    public override bool A 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return base.A  ? base.A : A;
        }
        set
        {
            this.A = value;
        }
    }
}
```