# C# variable definition from file

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, declaration

I have a C# project in SharpDevelop.  I define the data variables in a class called, thusly:

```
using System;
namespace CSVHelperReadSample
{
    class DataRecord1
    {
        public string TimeWhen { get; set;}
        public float IconAltitude { get; set; }
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can I dynamically change the declarations in DataRecord1 by reading in a csv file?  The csv file would have four columns and n rows, where column 1 = public, column 2 = type (string, float), column 3 = dataFieldName, and column 4 = { get; set;}.

Comment: So you want to set your properties based on what you find in the csv file?

Comment: Once a class is compiled, it is that until you change the source and recompile. If you are looking to dynamically add properties, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c) If you are trying to read from a variable length/width item like a csv file, you might consider a dictionary rather than a class.

Comment: I just want to be able to set the class definitions externally at the time of compilation, based on reading a csv file that contains the declarations.

Comment: The C# compiler will only compile C# code.  You'll need to either write your own compiler to "compile" CSV data (one does not exist that I know of) or use something like [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate C# code from your CSV file.

Comment: I've experimented with T4 templates per @D-Stanley (e.g., https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx).  I'm trying to modify this example to read the variable properties from a csv file with using     (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\varFile.csv")), but I'm failing.  Happy to write directly.