# Name Variable using string .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, deserialization

I'm working on a deserialization class in .NET, I have to develop a method that provides to me with a variable name that is stored in a string.

I have a string such as:

```
string string_name = "this_is_going_to_be_var_name";
```

Now what can I do so that my code dynamically declares a variable named this_is_going_to_be_var_name?

So to clear things up: There will be a deserialization class that will declare variables of the same names as strings provided as input with their PARENT TYPES as per wish of the Higher Level Programmer/User.

**For Example: In javascript/jQuery, when I fetch JSON by making a request, the interpreter declares variable(s)/array(s) of the same name and assigns values to them. If {"var_name":"var_value"} is a JSON string, the interpreter will create a variable named var_name and will assign "var_value" to it such as json_data_object.var_name.**

Comment: I don't understand, explode in PHP merely splits a string into parts separated by a separator, that has nothing to do with declaring a variable by the same name.

Comment: deserialize from what? maybe the functionality you are building already exists?

Comment: I guess I got a little confused there, no I didn't meant explode, I mean something else, wait let me edit it, so I can explain myself a little better. @MystereMan

Comment: I don't believe that's true for .NET @NeilThompson

Comment: Maybe I'm going a way that you perceive as wrong, which doesn't negates the probability of it being right? I haven't settled for any solution yet, so it can't be good, bad or near impossible to implement? "you don't want to follow the advice of those willing to help" - if that was true, I wouldn't be here. Take a deep breathe and think what you wanna say.. @spender - My previous post got deleted so I couldn't answer there.

Comment: @DerpyDerp You're going a way that the language itself perceives as wrong. People are trying to tell you this, but you're being stubborn and telling them they're wrong because you're so dead set on this dynamic variable naming plan.

Comment: Can a language perceive something as wrong? Does a language has the conscience needed to perceive something as wrong? <br/> On the other note, I'm just trying to accomplish attaching values with names at runtime. @Coeffect

Comment: The `Dictionary<string, object>` is definitely the way to go. I don't see any advantage to the item being an actual variable declaration, as it wouldn't exist so you couldn't use it with intellisense anyway.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't. C# variables are all statically declared.

The best thing you can do is create a dictionary and use keys instead of variable names.

```
// Replace object with your own type
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myDictionary.Add("this_is_going_to_be_var_name", value_of_the_variable);
// ...
// This is equivalent to foo($this_is_going_to_be_var_name) in PHP
foo(myDictionary["this_is_going_to_be_var_name"]);
```

Comment: How would this dictionary approach help in case of arrays in arrays. We don't know for sure about the dimensions of arrays. @forcey

Comment: `object` can hold anything, including arrays of arrays. If you want it look even more like PHP you can replace `object` with `dynamic`.

Comment: The fact that I understood what you needed and answered your question doesn't mean I would consider this a good question. Try to ask better next time :-)

Comment: It still doesn't answers me in the correct manner and I don't think it's an appropriate answer. Try answering better next time :) @forcey

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, variable names are defined at compile time, not run time. 
One approach is to create a dictionary or hash table to map string names to objects to sort of achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by

> my code **dynamically declares a variable named**
>   this_is_going_to_be_var_name?

but the .Net version of what `explode` does in PHP is `Split`:

```
string[] zz = "this_is_going_to_be_var_name".Split('_');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think on the moment (I haven't tested it so I have no clue if it is possible), is to have a object of type dynamic and then try to set the fields at runtime using reflection and InvokeMember(), which I can give a chance that it will work since the there is no validation on objects of type dynamic.

**UPDATE:**
I have tested it with ExpendoObject and InvokeMember doesn't appear to work (at least not with the default binder, but I haven't tested it with DynamicObject and allthough I don't give it to much chances to work you might still try it, you can check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx on how to use DynamicObject.

Take a look on [Dynamically adding properties to an ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938397/dynamically-adding-properties-to-an-expandoobject?rq=1) which essentially describes a method in which the dynamic object is being cast as a IDictionary and then you can add properties to it by using the standard dictionary access, while they are actually getting properties of the object.

I tested it in a sample project by having a dynamic object of type ExpendoObject and then I add another variable that referenced it using type IDictionary, and then I tried to set and get properties on both, as in the following example:

```
dynamic test = new ExpandoObject(); 
//reference the object as a dictionary
var asDictinary = test as IDictionary<string, Object>;

//Test by setting it as property and get as a dictionary
test.testObject = 123;
Console.Write("Testing it by getting the value as if it was a dictionary");
Console.WriteLine(asDictinary["testObject"]);

//Test by setting as dictionary and get as a property
//NOTE: the command line input should be "input", or it will fail with an error
Console.Write("Enter the varible name, ");
Console.Write("note that for the example to work it should the word 'input':");
string variableName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter the varible value, it should be an integer: ");           
int variableValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
asDictinary.Add(variableName, variableValue);
Console.WriteLine(test.input);//Provided that the command line input was "input"
```

(Still however in your case since you will anyway not access the properties directly in code I don't see the need for it and you would probably be able to use a Dictionary directly, and I don't understand why you need them to be properties of the object, which is only needed if you want to reference them at compile time.

But maybe I am misunderstanding you and you are looking for a dynamic variable and not for a dynamic property [something that is available in PHP using the $$ syntax], if this is the case then note that in c# there are no variables at all as everything is encapsulated in a object).

You can also take a look in [How can I dynamically add a field to a class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646258/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-field-to-a-class-in-c-sharp) for more answers.

Comment: You need to expand on that, and I too believe Reflection could be a piece to the puzzle, but again, I have no clue. @yohal

Comment: Check out the dynamic type and the reflection InvokeMember method, what I am suggesting is that maybe you can for type dynamic use InvokeMember on nonexisting members, and although I am not giving to much chances that it will work still I haven't a chance to test it, so if you want you can at least give it a try