# How to add a variable to a class dynamically with out modifying the original class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to add a variable to a class without modifying the original class. The class can not be modified in anyway because it is tie to an api and would cause build errors if modified. Currently the view is displaying all the variables  in the class,  I want to add a variable to this class during runtime to display to the view.

```
public class EventSummaryDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }
    public int EventCode { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public int DigitalPositionMM { get; set; }
    public string ControllerType { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'dynamically'? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use `Reflection` to do that...or you can use the `ExpandoObject` class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think, you could create your custom class and then map your fields to Dto.

Comment: You can't. You can create a new class that inherits from this one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646258/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-field-to-a-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: It really would help if you explained why you want to do this.

Comment: Can i see an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically, this is what you would use inheritance for

```
public class ExpandedEventSummary : EventSummaryDto
{
    public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```